# [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. -vue-simple-uploader

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

My component looks like below.

```
<template>
            <uploader class="uploader-example">
                <uploader-unsupport></uploader-unsupport>
                <uploader-drop>
                    <p>Drop files here to upload or</p>
                    <uploader-btn>select files</uploader-btn>
                    <uploader-btn :directory="true">select folder</uploader-btn>
                </uploader-drop>
                <uploader-list></uploader-list>
            </uploader>

</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
    import uploader from 'vue-simple-uploader';
    @Component({
        components: {
            Uploader: uploader,
        },
    })
    export default class In extends Vue {

    }
</script>
```

My shims-vue.d.ts file looks like below:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue';
  export default Vue;
}

declare module 'vue-simple-uploader';
```

With above code I am getting below error:

[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

and also uploader component is not being rendered.

I have used below package.

https://github.com/simple-uploader/vue-uploader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're binding the library incorrectly — it's written as a [Vue plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html), not as a standalone component.

The correct usage is outlined in [the project readme](https://github.com/simple-uploader/vue-uploader#usage):

```
// main.ts
import Vue from 'vue'
import uploader from 'vue-simple-uploader'

Vue.use(uploader)
```

No further import as a subcomponent is necessary, as it's registered globally. This isn't good practice, but it's how the component is written.

Comment: aha. And I was thinking everything as a component so far. I thought plugin was a past (plugin I had just watched videos about. Now I got it clear.) Because of this knowledge, marking your answer as answer.

Comment: @AnonymousCreator Vue plugins are common and often very useful (see [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) and [Vue-i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) for example), they're just not the best way to wrap a standalone component. It works, but it's an antipattern.

Comment: I feel the same. this should be component. Thanks for more resources.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to init the uploader in the main app.js file :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import uploader from 'vue-simple-uploader'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.use(uploader)
```

or try this :

```
@Component({
    components: {
        uploader: uploader,
    },
})
```